# Using the word "without" as a substitute for "instead of"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

So I came across the following sentence:

> Use the staircase without a lift or an escalator to save energy.

Even though the description suggested that there is nothing wrong with it, 
I felt a bit uneasy about using the word "without" here, as I thought that it would be more natural if it used "instead of".

I did some research, and I got the following definition for "without".

> with the absence, omission, or avoidance of; not with; with no or none of; lacking:

I was a bit confused because when I consider the meaning "avoidance", it seemed to make sense.
As I'm not particularly fluent at English, I thought that I should ask.

So I am curious if it's alright to use "without" in place of "instead of" and if not, why.
Thank you.

Comment: I think, no. Reasons, not sure.

Comment: 'Use the staircase without a lift or an escalator to save energy.' is unacceptable. 'Instead of', 'rather than' or ', and not a lift or an escalator, to save energy.' are needed. Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: It was one of the questions on an online test website(?) and the question was to choose all the appropriate words to fill in the blank(which is where the word "without" is.). I only chose "instead of", but the answer was "instead of" **and** "without". @EdwinAshworth

Comment: So much for some of these _learn 'English'_ websites.

Comment: Yep. I'm guessing that the test publishers didn't do enough research. Quite concerned of the people who thought it's correct because of them. @EdwinAshworth

Comment: If you could use _without_, it would be reasonable to expect to be able to use _with_ as well. And using a staircase _with_ a lift or escalator seems a tremendous physical challenge.

Comment: @oerkelens Come to think of it, yes. That does make sense. Maybe that's the reason why I thought that the usage is unnatural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer:

For the sentence you've provided, I'd say, no. Using *without* in place of *instead of* does not present the same idea. So just use *instead of* and avoid any confusion.

Suppose a similar sentence is:

> 1. Order a coffee **instead of** tea.

Your two options are tea and coffee. In this sentence, you're preferring one over the other.

> 2. Order a coffee **without** tea.

It does not convey the same idea as sentence 1.

> 3. Order a coffee **without** sugar.

This makes sense, but is conveying a different idea.

Comment: So-if I understood correctly-the sentence I wrote will still have a similar concept of advising to use the staircase, but it would not be the **exact** same?

Comment: @KiwiLee just use _instead of_ and avoid any confusion.